# CSS doesn't load background pictures for <header>

Tags: html, css, background, load

Right now I'm working on an HTML5+CSS3 homework. I'd want to have a dynamic header image.
So ot was awesom 'till the pont when I made it "dynamic".

Currently: There isn't any kind of header in my page.
Plase help. :)
Here the CSS:

```
header{
position:static;
margin: 0 auto;
background:url(img/desk_header.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<header></header>
```

Comment: You need to set the header's height to something. If you look at the element via some inspector it'll probably have some nonzero width and 0px height.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/X8U8Q/ You probably need to add content or height so that it have height: 0.

Comment: For the Dekstop the right code is:

CSS3:

    header{
 margin:0 auto;
 position:fixed;
 left:25%;
 right:25%;
 background:url(img/desk_header.png);
    }

    .meret{
 height:100%; 
 width:auto;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
    }

HTML5:

    <header class="meret"></header>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting width and height might help

```
header{
  position:static;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background:url(img/desk_header.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```